# Chapter 3, question 20 part b of Spivak's Calculus 4th edition

Tags: real-analysis

Someone gave a great answer to the post "Chapter 3, question 20 part b of Spivak's Calculus 3rd edition."  (Please see that post for context)  But it's assumed that |f(y)-f(x)|≤(y−x)^2/n

How does Spivak prove this inequality?  It isn't in edition 4.

I know that if you modify the inequality you can prove that |f(y/n)-f(x/n)|≤((y-x)/n)^2

Doesn't the first equation ignore the effect of dividing the interval y-x by n on the value of f(y) - f(x)?

Comment: Can you post the entire problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have Spivak's book, so I don't know how he proved $|f(y) - f(x)| \le (y - x)^2/n$. However, I can show you how to get that inequality. Without loss of generality, assume $x < y$. Fix a positive integer $n$, and consider the points $x_k:= x + (y-x)k/n$ for $k = 0,2,\ldots, n$. For $1\le k \le n$, the interval $[x_{k-1},x_k]$ has length $(y-x)/n$. Thus, by the condition on $f$, $$\tag{*}|f(x_k) - f(x_{k-1})| \le \left(\frac{y-x}{n}\right)^2\quad (k = 1,2,\ldots, n)$$

Since

$$f(y) - f(x) = f(x_n) - f(x_0) = \sum_{k = 1}^n [f(x_{k-1}) - f(x_k)],$$

then by the triangle inequality and (*),

$$|f(y) - f(x)| \le \sum_{k = 1}^n |f(x_k) - f(x_{k-1})| \le \sum_{k = 1}^n \left(\frac{y-x}{n}\right)^2 = n\left(\frac{y-x}{n}\right)^2 = \frac{(y-x)^2}{n}.$$